# mysql count instances of different variables inside a column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find a way to summarize and count the number of different instances inside a mysql table.

My table looks something like this:

ID | Name
1 | jersey [1]
2 | computer [1]
3 | hammer [3]
4 | axe [h]
5 | jacket [h]
6 | boots [d]

What i would like to achieve is the following result:

Short Name | Count
[1]        | 2
[3]        | 1
[h]        | 2
[d]        | 1

Comment: Thank you Tim for the answer, it defiantly helps me understand some more mysql querieis, however maybe I should have given a better description of the name.  The name can be something like "These are all jersey [1]" so there is not one word, a break and then the [1]. that i am looking to count.  What is constant in all of the names is the two square brackets, a number between 1 to 60, a letter h and a letter d.

Answer (score 0):

We can try aggregating with the help of `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', -1) AS `Short Name`, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY 1;
```

Note that, from a table design point of view, it would be desirable to have the short name as its own separate column.  This would make the above query even simpler, because we wouldn't have to make use of costly (and non sargable) string operations.